# Group and Ordering in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a query in SQL that can display the top selling book. for this I need to do a inner join and I get a problem after I did the inner join. Here is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW mostpopularbookssold AS 
SELECT     Count(orders.book_id) AS numberofbookssold , 
           Top(1) books.[Name] 
FROM       orders 
INNER JOIN books 
ON         books.id=orders.book_id 
GROUP BY   books.[Name] 
select * 
FROM   mostpopularbookssold
```

Comment: MySQL != MS Sql Server

Comment: What is "get a problem"? Even with the right syntax, what top 1 book do you expect to get?

Comment: where did that top(1) predicate come from? it is misplaced and probably unnecessary as the group by already ensures that every book title is mentioned only once.

Comment: Getting multipart identifier Orders.Book_ID could not be bound,  incorrect syntax near top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TOP(1)` should be placed at the start of your query, after `SELECT`. Furthermore you have to make an ordering by the books sold:

```
CREATE VIEW MostPopularBooksSold
AS
SELECT TOP(1)
    COUNT(Orders.Book_ID) AS NumberOfBooksSold
    , Books.[Name] 
FROM [the database name].[schema name].[Orders] AS Orders
INNER JOIN [the database name].[schema name].[Books] AS Books
    ON Books.ID = Orders.Book_ID
GROUP BY Books.[Name]
ORDER BY COUNT(Orders.Book_ID) DESC
```

You should replace *the database name* with the name of the database, in which you have created the corresponding tables and you have replace the `schema name` with the schema name, under which you have created the corresponding tables (usually this is the dbo, if you haven't stated explicitly a schema name).

Comment: on the " FROM Orders" I get a error stating that Orders is an invalid object

Comment: @Grootpoot Does the name of the corresponding table is `Orders`. If so try to use the whole name using the schema. `[the database name].[schema name].[Orders]`

Comment: can you maybe help?

Comment: @Grootpoot Did you tried to replace `Orders` with `[the database name].[schema name].[Orders]`?  The database name is easy, it's the name of the database, in which you have created your table. The schema name is usually `dbo`, if you haven't alter it. Give this a try and let me know. Thanks'

Comment: Now on the line of the inner join I get the error that books is a invalid object name

Comment: Do you have a table named Books?

Comment: @Grootpoot Nice...I think that now you get what's the error...Do exactly the same thing, replace Books with `[the database name].[schema name].[Books]`. In order the query to be more read-able you have to aliases both table names. e.g After `[the database name].[schema name].[Orders]` write `AS Orders` and after the `[the database name].[schema name].[Orders]` write `AS Orders`.